# EL Expression binding in JSF

Tags: jsf, el

I have an EL expression : "#{tab.partColumnComparator.onChangeSortBy}" in an xhtml file.
While 'tab' is equal  to the name of a managedBean 'XYZ.java'

Can anyone tell me where is this wiring implemented please?

I searched the whole workspace with the java file name and all xml files , but couldnt find it.

Thank you in advance.

Lucky.

Comment: Just Open your project in Netbeans IDE then Ctr+click on the #{tab. ... might redirect to associated class

Comment: @Jitesh : nope didnt work ! :(. What would be in Eclipse ?

Comment: Also the starting class "tab" is the managed bean name which should be either declared in xml or in java class to use. Or Your project contains "Tab.java" class then jsf will automatically use "#{tab. .." for EL. So try to search file with "Tab.java" or search "tab" in java or xml file. And if not found then i wondered how your project is working

Comment: What do you mean by where the wiring is implemented ? You mean where is the EL implementation in the Java API ? Or how and where your managed beans are declared ? Please be more precise in your question.

Comment: @Jitesh: Yes I see Tab.java file. So how to go from there ?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan : Where is the managed bean declared ?

Comment: Either in config file beans.xml or in Java classes with the use of annotations. Are you sure 'tab' is not an element of a list ?

Comment: There are few java classes with the use of annotations and its easily identifiable using the bean name. but this 'tab', I am not able to find the class, unless I go the other way of searching the method name after tab and making an educated guess on the java class. Yes I am sure 'tab' is not an element of a list

Comment: Then search partColumnComparator inthat file u ll find its implementation

Comment: @Jitesh: thanks for your help. There are few predefined methods in interface Tab.java which are overridden  based on requirements in respective java classes. Like String getXhtml(); in XYZ.java class is     protected String getXhtmlPage() {
  return xyz.xhtml;
 } . So I guess when I have a xhtml file , I will first search for the file name in the java files ? and thereby find out the tab value ? Err hope I am not confusing you. Sorry : - /